# Nothing was stored in database when mode=aspectj

Tags: java, spring, transactions, persistence

I build an application which use Hibernate JPA2 + Spring. I have problem with transaction. I'm using declarative transaction in my POJO classes. In context config I have next line:

```
<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

I copy it from book. But when I try persist some of my entity to database, then nothing will be stored and no error or exception occurs. I tried remove attribute "mode" from xml tag, here it is:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

After that all works fine.
So for what is a "mode" attribute? When I remove it, then will be my transaction work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mode="aspectj"` only works if you compile your code with the aspectj compiler (or have load-time weaving enabled) and have `spring-aspects.jar` on the classpath.

Comment: When I remove it, then will be my transaction work correctly?
What are the benefit of mode="aspectj"

Comment: @pierre with mode=aspectj, the behaviour is actually added to your classes, whereas mode=proxy emulates the behaviour at runtime. mode=proxy can only work on public methods, mode=aspectj on all methods. aspectj is much more powerful, but until you know what aspectj is and does, you should use mode=proxy

Comment: +1. Read up on aspectj and load-time weaving and compare it with spring's AOP using run-time proxying and this will become a lot clearer.